# Determine if subset of $C[a,b]$ is Compact

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $X = C[a,b] $ with the standard uniform metric. Let $g \in C[a,b]$

Prove that $F = \{f \in C[a,b] : |f(x)| \leq |g(x)| \; \; \forall x \in [a,b] \}$ is a compact subset $\iff g = 0$

$\impliedby$ is clear.

I've got a potential solution for the other direction and need someone to let me know if it's ok.

Suppose $g \neq 0$ . WLOG assume $\exists \; s$ s.t $g(s) > 0 $

By Continuity of $g \; \exists \; \delta >0$ s.t  $ \; \forall y \in (s- \delta, s + \delta) \subset [a,b] \implies \frac{g(s)}{2} < g(y) < \frac{3g(s)}{2}$

Now pick an Interval $[ \alpha, \beta]\subset g^{-1}\big(\frac{g(s)}{2},\infty\big) \subset [a,b] $

Let $$f_n(z) = \frac{z^2}{z^2 +(1-nz)^2} \; \; \forall z \in [0,1]$$

Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ but not uniformly since $f_n(\frac 1n) = 1$

Let $\phi = \frac{(t-\alpha)}{\beta - \alpha}$ be a homeomorphism from $[\alpha, \beta]$ to $ [ 0,1] $

Let $$h_n = \begin{cases}  \frac{g(s)}{2} \circ f_n \circ  \phi & x \in[\alpha,\beta] \\ 0 & x\in [a,b] \setminus [\alpha,\beta] \end{cases}$$

Then $h_n$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and since $ |h_n(x)| \leq |g(x)|$

Then $h_n \in F \; \forall \; n \; \;$  but $h_n\big(\frac{\beta - \alpha}{n} + \alpha\big) = \frac{g(s)}{2} > 0 \; \forall \; n$ and so $h_n$ cannot converge uniformly either, nor can any subsequence. Thus $F$ is not Compact

Am I missing something, or is this ok?

Comment: I have two small remarks to your exposition.

1. In the definition of $h_n$, you should probably write "\frac{g(s)}{2} \cdot f_n " instead of "$\frac{g(s)}{2} \circ f_n$".

2. (This might be nitpicking) Having both intervals $[\alpha, \beta]$ and $(s-\delta, s+\delta)$ seems a bit redundant to me (although perfectly correct and thorough, in fact). I'd use $(s-\delta, s+\delta)$ instead of $(\alpha, \beta)$ (the endpoints don't matter, because functions are zero there anyway) or the other way round: "by continuity there exists $(\alpha, \beta)\ni s$, such that..." and give details if asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's a problem: $f_n(1) = \frac 1{n^2 - 2n +2}$, so $h_n$ isn't continuous. Regardless, your idea is all right: take a sequence without uniformly convergent subsequence and scale it to fit under $g$.

Your example can be easily fixed: eg. extend $f_n$ with some piece of linear function so that $f_n$ ends with $0$. However, we can just define $f_n$ to be suitable piecewise linear, or even simpler.

Here's some example:
$$
k_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac 12 g(s)\cdot \sin \Big(\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}\cdot \pi n\Big),
 & \text{for } x\in \Big[\alpha, \alpha + \frac 1n (\beta-\alpha)\Big],\\
0,& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Check the values for $x-\alpha = 0,\ \frac 1{2n} (\beta-\alpha),\ \frac 1n (\beta-\alpha)$.
What I did was to take $\sin \pi x$ on $[0,1]$ (and $0$ outside), scale it to $[0, \frac 1 n]$, so I got an appropriate sequence on $[0,1]$, and then scale it (by your $\phi$, actually) inside $[\alpha,\beta]$ and under $g$.

Remarks:

1. Of course many examples can be constructed in the same way. My first idea (now and several years ago, when given similar problem) was a piecewise linear function with a peak around $\frac 1n$ and up to $1$ (and $0$ around, and rescaled). Another was $nx(2-nx)$ ($= 1- (nx-1)^2$), but I settled with sine, because it seemed shorter and more elegant.
2. The formulas can be made even briefer: if we define $M= \frac 1{\beta-\alpha}$, or if we denote the interval where $g$ is "large" by $[\alpha, \alpha + \frac 1M]$ to begin with, we get:
   $$
   k_n(x) = 
   \begin{cases}
   \frac 12 g(s)\cdot \sin \big(\pi Mn(x-\alpha) \big),
    & \text{for } x\in \big[\alpha, \alpha + \frac 1{Mn}\big],\\
   0,& \text{otherwise.}
   \end{cases}
   $$

Comment: $k_n$ doesn't seem to be continuous at $\alpha+{\pi\over n}(\beta-\alpha)$, $k_n(\alpha+{\pi\over n}(\beta-\alpha))={g(s)\over2}\sin(\pi^2)\neq0$. That $\pi$ in the interval is a typo, right?

Comment: Of course, @Jack , thank you. I'll correct right away.
Btw, I'm sorry for your life ;) You seem to be doing pretty well here, though :)